# Поиск элемента по имени в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Мне надо на форме именно найти элемент (`button`, `panel` и т.д.) по его `name` (имени переменной). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Метод [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) - выполняет поиск элементов
>   управления по их свойству `Name` и создает массив из всех элементов
>   управления, которые соответствуют условиям поиска.

Поиск элементов, совпадающих по имени, будет выглядеть так:

```
var textBoxes = this.Controls.Find("textBox", true);
```

Если необходимо просто найти в коллекции элемент по ключу, тут нужно знать ключ (имя элемента), то вот так:

```
var textBox = this.Controls["textBox1"];
```

Проверить, содержится ли элемент в контролах можно с помощью метода [`Control.ControlCollection.ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx). К примеру, взять элемент по ключу будет правильнее, если заранее проверить, содержится ли он в коллекции, код будет выглядеть так:

```
var name = "textBox1";
if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(name))
{
    var textBox = this.Controls[name]; 
    // делаем с этим элементом то, что нам нужно
}
```