# Обращение к элементам формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим у меня есть 10 textBox ( textBox1, textBox2, ... textBox10 ). 
Как при нажатии на кнопку, с помощью цикла, взять значение из каждого textBox и дальше использовать.

И если имена textBox у меня другие, например (square, perimeter, amount, size, radius...) и все эти имена в массиве, как обратится по очереди к каждому их них и взять значение из каждого.

Comment: Как пройтись циклом по массиву Вы знаете? Если да, то осталось только обратиться к `textBox` по имени. Как это сделать написано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564289/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-winforms

Comment: спасибо, про циклы я знаю, мне нужно было узнать только как обратиться к элементу по его имени.

Comment: Есть еще способ - единожды проинициализировать свой массив этими элементами и работать с массивом

Comment: Вы работаете с WinForms?

Comment: Да с  WinForm, но я уже разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] num = {
  "textBox1",
  "textBox2",
  "textBox3"
};
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++) {
  var textBox = this.Controls[num[i]];
  sum += Convert.ToInt16(textBox.Text);
}
MessageBox.Show("Сумма введенных чисел = " + Convert.ToString(sum));
```

Comment: А почему не создать сразу массив TextBox'ов?

Comment: @АндрейNOP потому что из 100 полей для подсчета я использую только допустим 10 с определенными значениями, некоторые записываются в файл, а остальные используются для других операций. поэтому массивы нужны разные, те 10 Box-ов находятся в массиве - totalBox, те которые в файл записываются - fileBox, остальные - otherBox

Answer (score 0):

Циклом ForEach пройтись по TextBox'ам и получить нужные данные.

```
var val = "";
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox)
  {
    val += ((TextBox)x).Text;
  }
}
```